# ASP.NET MVC using ViewData in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am currently building a website in ASP.NET MVC. I am trying to access ViewData in javascript.

Is there any way that I can access a string value using javascript in a View that was stored in ViewData in a Controller Action. ( I am not able to figure out the right syntax ).

I wish to do something like..

```
var str = ViewData["Text"];
```

I tried the following:

var str = <%=ViewData["Text"] %>

but it didn't work.

Can someone please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Like this (Razor):

```
var str = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["Text"]));
```

or (WebForms), using the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) (and after importing theproper namespace to your webform - `System.Web.Script.Serialization`):

```
var str = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["Text"])) %>;
```

And please don't use ViewData in an ASP.NET MVC application. Use view models and strongly typed views so that your code looks like this:

```
var str = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Text) %>;
```

This technique is even cooler as now you can JSON serialize the entire view model:

```
var model = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;
var str = model.Text;
```

Comment: this is a very old post but I'll try my luck: Just where would you place that code? Inside `@section Scripts`, things like `@Html...` doesn't work

Comment: `var str = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["Text"]));` perfect!

Answer (score 11):

That should be:

```
var str = '<%= ViewData["Text"] %>';
```

Comment: No, that's very bad. Never use something like this in a real world application. What if the text contains a quote? This code is pretty vulnerable to XSS attacks especially if this Text comes from user input.

Comment: He was *so* close already, I thought it would be more helpful to answer the question he had than make it over-complicated.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question!!! This is an invitation to XSS attacks and advertising bad practices. We are not talking about over-complicating here. We are talking about answering the question. How can you possible say that this answers the question? I mean this code will break soon and it will be subject to yet another question on SO. I can't believe that this question was upvoted and you haven't deleted it yet so that it doesn't get indexed as someone might actually use this in his application.

Comment: Your answer is clearly more widely applicable.  Given your comments here and in your own answer, I'm sure he'll understand to encode and escape if he expects apostrophes or user-generated data in his ViewData.  I also believe that him seeing what was wrong with his own, more simple code is valuable.

Comment: I agree. Darin's is the proper answer - but it's good to know the other (albeit "not recommended") way too. +1 to both of you.