# MVC: Use string variables of a view as parameter to a javascript function call

Tags: javascript, function, razor, parameters

How can I call a javascript function within a view(cshtml) and pass some string variables (defined in the view)to be used as parameters for the function call?

Say the function javascriptFunction uses 2 parameter. I will usually call it as `javascriptFunction('param1', 'param2')` . But now I want to pass it some variables.

```
string y = "this is a string"
string x = "another"
javascriptFunction(y, x)
```

I have tried javascriptFunction(@y, @x), javascriptFunction('@y', '@x')  but this does not work

Comment: Try putting quotes around them like this -> ("@y","@x")

Comment: tried that but having syntax error\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to distinguish between javascript code and server-side code. Also encode your javascript strings:

```
@{
string y = "this is a string";
string x = "another";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function javascriptFunction(first,second)
    {
        alert(first+' '+second);
    }

    javascriptFunction(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(y)), @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(x)));
</script>
```

[Using Razor within javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599169/using-razor-within-javascript)

Comment: Try putting single quotes around the 2 variables in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could load some variables using the answer from this link and pass them into your function.

[ASP.NET MVC using ViewData in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863094/asp-net-mvc-using-viewdata-in-javascript)