# How do I add Viewdata to my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.NET MVC Project. I am calling one stored procedure in my controller and taking that result into my viewdata like this :

```
 var sp = callsp(parameter1, paramter2)

 if(abovespcontainsnoresult)
 {
       viewdata["result"] = "This sp doesn't consists any results";
    }
```

Now I have to pass this to my script function. I have script which enables button when i select list from dropdown :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#button").change(function (e) {

         if ($(this).val() != '')  {
             $("#button1").attr('disabled', false);
             $("#button2").attr('disabled', false);
             $("#button3").attr('disabled', false);
             $("#button4").attr('disabled', false);
         }
      }
```

Now what I want to do is add viewdata result to this script and check whether it is null or not. I tried like this :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#button").change(function (e) {

          if ($(this).val() != '' &&  ($(@ViewData["result"].ToString()) != "")) 
        {
             $("#button1").attr('disabled', false);
             $("#button2").attr('disabled', false);
             $("#button3").attr('disabled', false);
             $("#button4").attr('disabled', false);
         }
      }
```

But script doesnt work if I add this condition. So how do I check viewdata result into my script and check whether it is null or not ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC using ViewData in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863094/asp-net-mvc-using-viewdata-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the value of `$(ViewData["result"].ToString())` to a JavaScript variable, and then use that variable in the `if` statement.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").change(function (e) {
        var result = $('@ViewData["result"].ToString()');

        if ($(this).val() != '' && result !== '') 
        {
             $("#button1").attr('disabled', false);
             $("#button2").attr('disabled', false);
             $("#button3").attr('disabled', false);
             $("#button4").attr('disabled', false);
         }
      }
```

You were on the right track initially.

Answer (score 2):

If you put ticks it will work.

```
 '@ViewData[result]'
```

If it is an external JS file (script is not coded in view) it will not work