# How to parse objects from ViewBag to JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I am trying to parse an object from ViewBag to Javascript without luck. I have tried so far with jQuery/razor/mixed syntax...to no avail. When I tried with `Json.Encode()`, I get an "error not defined".

**Class**

```
class Story 
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Description{get;set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index(Story _story) 
{
    List<Location> Locations = this.context.Locations.ToList();
    ViewBag.story = _story;
    return View(context.Locations);
}
```

**View**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var story = JSON.parse("@ViewBag.story");
        var story2try = '@(ViewBag.story)';

        console.log(@ViewBag.story.Id);
        console.log(story);
        console.log(story2try);
});
```

The thing is the first log gets printed so for primitive data types such as strings/int/long it works but not for objects. I get this error afterwards:

> Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0 SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0

Comment: What does the rendered – as seen by the browser – view look like.

Comment: `'@(ViewBag.story)'` will likely give you something like `Story` - ie the type.ToString().  Your controller is returning an *object* not JSON, so there's nothing parse.  You should be able to just use `var story = {}; story.Description = '@ViewBag.story.Description'; story.Id = @ViewBag.story.Id;`

Comment: Did you try: `var story=JSON.parse("@((new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(ViewBag.Story))";`

Comment: @Richard : i get the name of the type rendered

Comment: @freedomn-m  so basically i have to take property by property to get all the object? And no i didn't try System.Web.Script...

Comment: No, that's just an example to show how to get to specific properties.  If you want to *de*serialise something, you have to *serialise* it first (as per my 2nd comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after countless tries i managed to solve the problem :

**1**.Serialize my object in the controller as others pointed out using the Newtonsoft.Json library:

```
ViewBag._story =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_story);
```

**2**.In the view i would deserialize it using:

```
var _story=@(Html.Raw(ViewBag._story));
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to serialize the model object first (like it is suggested in comments) plus get its raw content (check the [ASP.NET MVC using ViewData in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863094/) thread), for example:

```
ViewBag.story = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_story);

$(function () {
    var story = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.story);
    alert(story.Id);
});
```

Comment: Is this in .NET Core too?

Comment: @user1913744 for Core use [JSON.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/10.0.3). (I would also use JSON.NET for Framework: it is faster and more flexible than any inbuilt JSON support.)

Comment: Where would you place that code? Is it posible to do this in the script block?